# R - How can we make a data frame with the value of the previous row with the same attribute?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this one:

```
DF = data.frame(ID=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), Class=c("X","Y","Z"), Period=c("12/12","13/04","13/08"))
DF
  ID Class Period
1  a     X  12/12
2  a     Y  13/04
3  a     Z  13/08
4  b     X  12/12
5  b     Y  13/04
6  b     Z  13/08
7  c     X  12/12
8  c     Y  13/04
9  c     Z  13/08
```

And I want for each combination of ID and Period to have a colunm with the Class value of the previous period for each ID. Something like this:

```
  ID Class Period PrevClass PrevPeriod
1  a     X  12/12      <NA>       <NA>
2  a     Y  13/04         X      12/12
3  a     Z  13/08         Y      13/04
4  b     X  12/12      <NA>       <NA>
5  b     Y  13/04         X      12/12
...
```

Just to add that in my data frame not all ID's will have a record for each period. I get the data from a database via ODBC, just been thinking if it would be easier to do it with SQL than to do it in R.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, are you sure you meant `"each combination of ID and Period"`  It looks like you simply want `"for each ID, the previous period and class"`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Might be a language issue, but is for each ID and Period I want the previous period and class.

Comment: could be a language issue.  It sounds to me though that you simply want `for each ID` to perform an action on other columns, as @codoremifa demonstrated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
DF = data.table(
ID=(rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3)), 
Class=(c("X","Y","Z")), 
Period=(c("12/12","13/04","13/08"))
)

#setting the order correctly, just in case
setkeyv(DF, c('ID', 'Class'))
#creating a column prevperiod with NA and the first n-1 elements of period within each ID
DF[,prevperiod := c(NA, head(Period,-1)), by = ID]
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for. Just the previous class was missing but i guess DF[,prevClass := c(NA, head(Class,-1)), by = ID] would do the trick!

Comment: be careful setting the key in situations were row-order is significant data, as this will re-rorder the `data.table`.  If the ordering used in `R` (or the underlying C code) is the same as the ordering  required, then there is no issue.  But if they differ then this will subtly throw off the results